# Singly linked List Find max,min

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

**This is a singly linked list and the professor wants me 2 find max min from define limit of singly list list ( similar 2 find array but use singly linked list instead ) however when i want 2 remove the number in singly linked list even if i'm not finish with it it get struck here is my code thank you for the contribution i'm a newbie and i don't know many things just a university student. and the number before menu is how many numbers that singly linked list can hold **

```
# include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int n; 
    Node*next;
};
bool isEmpty(Node*head)
{
    if (head==NULL)return true;
    else return false;
}
char menu()
{
    char choice;
    cout<<"Menu\n";
    cout<<"1.Add an item.\n";
    cout<<"2.Remove an item.\n";
    cout<<"3.Show The List.\n";
    cout<<"4.Exit.\n";
    cin>>choice;
    return choice;
}
void insert(Node*&head,Node*&last,int n) 
{
    Node*node = new Node(); // allocate memory 2 node let node be an abstract data
    node->n = n; // define data in the new node as new data (saving data define in there)
    node->next = NULL; // Let next of the new node as head
    head = node; // let pointer name head point new node
    last = node;
}
void append(Node*&head,Node*&last,int n)
{ 
    if(isEmpty(head)) insert(head,last,n);
    else
    {  
    Node*node = new Node(); // allocate memory 2 node let node be abstract data
    node->n = n; // define data in the new node as new data (saving data define in there)
    node->next = NULL; // This new node is going to be the last node, so make next of it as NULL
    last->next = node; // Change the next of last node
    last = node;
    }
}
void remove(Node*&head,Node*&last)
{
    if(isEmpty(head))cout<<"The List is Empty.\n";
    else if (head==last)
    {
        delete head;
        head == NULL;
        last == NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *node=head;
        head =head->next;
        delete node;
    }
}
void print(Node*node) // Function Prints Content of the singly linked list
{ 
    if(isEmpty(node))cout<<"The list is empty\n";
    else
    {
    cout << "The List contains: \n";
    while (node!= NULL) 
    { 
        cout<<node->n<<endl; 
        node = node->next; 
    }
    }
} 
int main()
{
    Node* head = NULL; // Start with empty List
    Node* last = NULL;
    char choice;int i,n,x;
    cin>>x;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
    choice = menu();
    switch(choice)
    {
        case '1': cout<<"Please enter a number: ";
                  cin>>n;
                  append(head,last,n);
                  break;
        case '2': remove(head,last);
                  break;
        case '3': print(head);
                  break;
        default: cout<< "System exit\n";
    } 
    } while(choice!='4'); return 0;
}
```

**Reality Output :
3 ( This is the number of data that singly-linked list can hold)
Menu

1. Add an item.
2. Remove an item.
3. Show the List.
4. Exit.
   1
   Please enter a number: 22
   Menu
5. Add an item.
6. Remove an item
7. Show The List.
8. Exit.
   1
   Please enter a number: 12
   Menu
9. Add an item.
10. Remove an item
11. Show The List.
12. Exit.
    2

- ( THE CURSOR COULDN'T DO ANYTHING ONLY BLINK ON THE BLANK BLACK OUTPUT)
  Expected Output
  3
  Menu

1. Add an item.
2. Remove an item.
3. Show the List.
4. Exit.
   1
   Please enter a number: 22
   Menu
5. Add an item.
6. Remove an item
7. Show The List.
8. Exit.
   1
   Please enter a number: 12
   Menu
9. Add an item.
10. Remove an item
11. Show The List.
12. Exit.
    2
    Menu
13. Add an item.
14. Remove an item
15. Show The List.
16. Exit.
    3
    The List contains
    12
    Menu
17. Add an item.
18. Remove an item
19. Show The List.
20. Exit.
    1
    Please enter a number: 22
    Menu
21. Add an item.
22. Remove an item
23. Show The List.
24. Exit.
    1
    Please enter a number: 34
    Menu
25. Add an item.
26. Remove an item
27. Show The List.
28. Exit.
    3
    The List contains
    12
    22
    34
    Max = 34 Min = 12

---

**P.S. I'M THANK U EVERYONE WHO COMES ANSWER ON THIS QUESTION BECAUSE I TRY WITH THIS QUESTION FOR 2 DAYS
THIS 1 IS HEAVY FOR ME**

Comment: Just change the professor.:)

Comment: Is your actual question "how to find the min and max in a singly-linked list?" Because that is not present in your question , I don't get what you mean by "it get struck here"

Comment: Your professor teaches this: `# include<bits/stdc++.h>`?  If so, I agree -- change the professor.

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Well he's kinda let us find the template code on the internet and discuss later he's busy and he's the head of computer science not only he's teaching but also freelancing i can't help but 2 know what's the hard thing for us but i guess it's make me more hungry in it.

Answer (score 4):

First error

```
    delete head;
    head == NULL;
    last == NULL;
```

should be

```
    delete head;
    head = NULL;
    last = NULL;
```

Use `==` for comparison, use `=` for assignment.

Your compiler really should warn you that a statement like `head == NULL;` achieves nothing. So either you need to pay attention to the wanrings that you compiler is giving (you should change your code until there are no compiler warnings) or if the compiler isn't warning you then you aren't using your compiler correctly. All compilers have options that cause them to give warnings for dubious code like this. If your compiler isn't warning you about this kind of code then you should take the time to find out how to make it so it does. Better to do that than waste two days trying to fix problems that the compiler could have told you about.

Second error has nothing to do with lists. Your loops in main are incorrect. You can see these better if you **indent your code correctly**. You should always do this, it saves time. Here's your code indented correctly.

```
cin>>x;
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    choice = menu();
    switch(choice)
    {
    case '1': 
        cout<<"Please enter a number: ";
        cin>>n;
        append(head,last,n);
        break;
    case '2':
        remove(head,last);
        break;
    case '3':
        print(head);
        break;
    default:
        cout<< "System exit\n";
    } 
}
while(choice!='4');
```

Now look at that `while` loop at the end. It looks like it is ending the `for` loop above, but there's no such thing as a `for ... while` loop. Instead that's a completely separate loop to the preceding `for` loop. It just loops for ever (because `choice` does not equal '4' and the loop never changes anything). That's why your code seems to freeze. Here's what your code should look like.

```
do
{
    choice = menu();
    switch(choice)
    {
    case '1': 
        cout<<"Please enter a number: ";
        cin>>n;
        append(head,last,n);
        break;
    case '2':
        remove(head,last);
        break;
    case '3':
        print(head);
        break;
    default:
        cout<< "System exit\n";
    } 
}
while(choice!='4');
```

I changed the two loops (`for` followed by `while`) into one `do ... while` loop and I got rid of the `x` variable which served no purpose. I guess you meant to write a `do ... while` loop all along but got confused about the syntax.

Overall the code is pretty good. You seem to understand pointers better than many newbies. The second error in particular was quite unusual and hard to spot. You should probably look into learning how to use a debugger. Bugs like this are easy to find with a debugger.

Comment: thank u for the solving i will try again i'm understand a bit of pointer but i think there's a lot of things that i never had been before in coding data.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is no great sense to declare the class Node

```
class Node
{
public:
    int n; 
    Node*next;
};
```

making all its data members public and then define stand-alone functions instead of defining class member functions.

The class Node should be an internal class of the class List that contains two pointers to the beginning and the end of the list because you are trying to define a two-sided singly-linked list.

Something like

```
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int value;
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;

public:
    List() = default;
    List( const List & ) = delete;
    List & operator =( const List & ) = delete;
    
    void push_front( int value )
    {
        head = new Node { value, head };
        if ( !tail ) tail = head;
    }
    
    void push_back( int value )
    {
        Node *new_node = new Node { value, nullptr };
        
        if ( tail )
        {
            tail = tail->next = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            head = tail = new_node;
        }
    }
    
    bool empty() const { return head == nullptr; }
    
    void pop_front()
    {
        if ( head )
        {
            delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
            if ( !head ) tail = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // and so on.
};
```

The function insert as it is written also does not make sense because it ignores the fact that the list can contain already nodes due to these statements.

```
node->next = NULL; // Let next of the new node as head
head = node; // let pointer name head point new node
last = node;
```

It would be better to write a function named like push_front that could be defined like

```
void push_front( Node * &head, Node * &last, int n ) 
{
    head = new Node { n, head };

    if ( !last )
    {
        last = head;
    }
}
```

It is better to rename the function append as push_back. The function can look like

```
void push_back( Node * &head, Node * &last, int n )
{ 
    if ( isEmpty( head ) ) 
    {
        push_front( head, last, n );
    }
    else
    {
        last = last->next = new Node { n, nullptr };  
    }
}
```

The function remove behaves as a function pop_front. So rename it The function shall not output any message. It is the user of the function should decide whether to output any message.
The function has several bugs.

For starters it uses the comparison operator instead of the assignment operator

```
    head == NULL;
    last == NULL;
```

If the list contains only one node that is deleted then the function forgets to set the pointer last to nullptr.

```
else
{
    Node *node=head;
    head =head->next;
    delete node;
}
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
bool pop_front( Node * &head, Node * &last )
{
    bool success = not isEmpty( head );

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *node = head;
        head = head->next;
   
        delete node;

        if ( !head ) last = head;
    }

    return success;
}
```

In main this construction

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    //...
} while(choice!='4'); return 0;
```

is incorrect. There is no any sense to use the for loop Use the do while loop like

```
do
{
    //...
} while(choice!='4'); 

return 0;
```

The statement under the label `default` does not make sense

```
default: cout<< "System exit\n"
```

It is better to write for example

```
default: 
    cout<< "Incorrect choice. Try again.\n";
    break;
```

Comment: Well My professor want me 2 use class instead of struct so that;s how hard for this work